# Android Wear Access Contacts

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts, wear-os

I have an app that interfaces extensively with the contacts `ContentProvider`. I am looking to introduce a Wear component to my app that will make use of contact data.

Is Wear able to directly access the contacts through a `ContentResolver` or does it have to be manually synced from the mobile device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such an API allows you to directly read contacts of your phone. You may have to consider the wearable app as a separate app from you phone side app. You should sync the contacts using the [Data Layer Api](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/index.html).