# Show Contacts list in Android Wear

Tags: android, wear-os, android-contacts

I’d like to access Contacts in Android Wear with a Sony Smartwatch 3.
I can see STARRED contacts in the smartwatch but I can not show them in a wear activity.

The permission is set in manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />`
```

I tried 2 ways without success:

1:

```
Cursor cursor;

cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

Log.v("MyActvt", "**********************NMB OF RAW = " + cursor.getCount());
/* the result is 0 in the previous Log.v*/

/* Then off course it does not enter the loop */
while (cntcts.moveToNext()) { 

                String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

}
```

2:

The same thing when I start an activity with the following code. The “No application can perform this action” is shown the the smartwatch screen

```
int PICK_CONTACT = 2;

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.v("MYActivity", "**********************RESULT CODE = "+resultCode);
        if (reqCode == PICK_CONTACT) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Uri contactData = data.getData();
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contactData, null, null, null, null);
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                    String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                }
             }
        }
}
```

Do you have any idea or did you see this probleme before?

Many thanks

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Have you been able to solve it?

Comment: It's not possible to do it. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/34541349/1764365 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/33073346/1764365